# Paypal Chained Payments, pass shipping address

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments, chained-payments

On my e-commerce website I'm using paypal for checkout. The flow is like this:
Buyer can select one or more products from one or more sellers. When paying I use chained payments. My paypal app account( primary) receives all the money and then I take my fee and send the rest to sellers(one or more). Everything is fine but I need to activate seller protection.
So far I implemented setPaymentsOption, but since I'm the primary receiver I cannot pass the shipping address from buyer to seller(s). I spoked with paypal support and they said that I shoud consider implementing IPN but I'm not sure how to do that.
 So for any ideas I will be grateful

Comment: I'm not following you when you say you can't include shipping because you're not the primary receiver..??  If you add a shipping address via SetPaymentOptions it should show up where necessary for seller protection.  IPN wouldn't solve that problem as that's a post-payment processing tool.  You need to get the shipping address to show up with the payment for seller protection.  IPN would let you save it in your own database (or wherever you want) but that won't make it eligible.  can you provide a sample of the SPO request you're using?

Comment: I am the primary receiver and I'm the only one that's getting the shipping address. It's a chained system. I receive all the money and then pass the rest. So basically I am the only one that's getting the shipping address and not the rest. So how can I pass the address to the others?

Comment: Ok, then yeah, using IPN would allow you to do that.  The address would get POSTed with the IPN data to your app, so then you can generate your own custom email with those details to send to your secondary receivers.

Comment: If I do so, all secondary receivers will have seller protection? please post any good tutorials or something like that( for IPN-shipping address) Thank you

Comment: Hi there.
Have you found any solution to this problem?

Comment: Hi, not yet, but for the moment I switched on parallel payments.